# changing Color of an ActionBar in several Activities

Tags: android, colors, background, android-actionbar

I have been stuck with this problem for a few hours. So here it is. I have 2 different activities. The first one has a menu with with the following options:blue,red,green,orange,purple. As soon as I click one of them the background color of the ActionBar of the first Activity changes with no problem. Now the issue starts when I try to do it for the second activity as well. so in other words, with one click of an option in a menu in a single Activity, change both ActionBars background colors in both Activities.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String Hex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button all_notes= (Button) findViewById(R.id.All_Notes);
        all_notes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,AllNotes.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                Toast.makeText(this, Hex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent_1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(intent_1);
                break;
            case R.id.blue:
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0099cc")));
                Hex="#0099cc";
                break;
            case R.id.pruple:
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#9933cc")));
                Hex="#9933cc";
                break;
            case R.id.orange:
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33")));
                Hex="#FFBB33";
                break; 
            case R.id.red:
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CC0000")));
                Hex="#CC0000";
                break;
            case R.id.green:
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#669900")));
                Hex="#669900";
                break;
            default:
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33")));
                Hex="#FFBB33";
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public String getHex()
    {
        return Hex;
    }
}


public class Settings extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity MA=new MainActivity();
        ActionBar bar=getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(MA.getHex())));
    }
}
```

So here you can see that I have Mainactivity which deals with the menu and allows the user input to select a color and Setting which takes the user selected color through the getHex method and changes its respective ActionBar background. 
This obviously does not work. And I have tried to find a simple and pretty code that can do this without success. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a good idea creating a new instance of `MainActivity` in the `onCreate` method of the `Settings` activity. Basically `MA.getHex()` will always return `null`.

If you just need to set the color of the action bar of the `Settings` activity to the one selected in the `MainActivity`, pass the hex value to the `Settings` activity as an extra in the intent (using `Intent.putExtra`) and get it in `Settings.onCreate` using `getIntent().getStringExtra(...)`.

Btw, I think you missed the call to `setContentView` in `Settings.onCreate`.

Comment: nope doesn't work thanks regardless I have learnt a bit about passing variables.The more general question would be if you had activity A and Activity B and Activity A contained an option in a menu that could change something for  both Activity A and B how would you go about this  thanks again!

Comment: Provided that activity B is started from activity A, there are several options: 1) pass the configuration data to B as an extra in the Intent (as we already discussed). 2) Set the configuration in a shared instance of a custom class (static member or Singleton for example) so B can read it when created. 3) Store the configuration data in a DB (`SQLiteDatabase`, for example) and retrieve it when B is created. 4) Store the configuration data in the Context's `SharedPreferences` and retrieve it when B is created.

Comment: In either case, as long as the code to "change something" in both A and B would be similar, you could create a common parent class which contains that shared code. That code would read the configuration from somewhere and change the Activity's appearance (in your example).